# Global function in Ionic 3

Tags: function, translation, global, ionic3

I would like to create a global function called "translate". As i know, i can define global variables and their values in the app.module.ts file. So i tried following code:

```
export function translate(string) {
  // i am not sure if it would make a difference if i would use var
  let ts = new TranslateService();
  return ts.get(string).subscribe(res=>{
    return res;
  }); 
}
```

So maybe i try to use the wrong class, maybe the mistake is somewhere else. I use the [ngx-translate Module](https://ionicframework.com/docs/developer-resources/ng2-translate/) (and it works great). Instead of always declaring to use the "TranslateService" (in every class where a translation is needed), i want to have a global function, where i can access the translations via only a function (i do not want to call another class...). You can see the code that i do like to use in the global function at the very end of the link ([ngx-translate](https://ionicframework.com/docs/developer-resources/ng2-translate/))

Thanks in advance.

global means for me, that something is accessible everywhere in the project.

Comment: NOTE: the example code DOES NOT WORK

Comment: its better if you could use a provider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think thats a very bad idea, even *if* you get it to work somehow by some messy hack thats not the way this is intended to work.

`TranslateService` is already a service you can inject in every class you need it. And injecting a service using Angulars dependency injection is the intended way to use it. If you are afraid that there will be multiple translate services in the end - don't worry, Angulars dependency injection system takes care of that.

I guess you want to do this because you always have to write `public translate: TranslateService` in your constructor. But if you export a function in your app.module you have to import it again in your class, so you will have to write `import { translate } from 'path/to/app.module/translate';` instead every time.